# When i log in windows automatically logs out

Tags: windows, login

I had this problem few days ago and most "solutions" called to create a new user account. yet sometimes it is an unnecessary , to broad action. In my case it was a (self edited) windows style which caused problems.

Symptoms:

- when i try to log onto a specific account i get thrown back to logon screen
- i can log into this account in safe mode
- there is no suspicious entries in autostart, virusscan is clean too
- **i do use third-party windows styles** via UxStyle or Uxtheme Multipatcher

Answer (score 0):

either

- go to `%windir%/Resources/Themes` and replace the used `*.msstyle` with default `aero` one

or

- go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager` and change the `DllName` value to `%Systemroot%\Resources\Themes\Aero\aero.msstyles`